# >> Login screen : From Batch to VBscript and again to Batch <<

Tags: vbscript, login-script, batch-file

I am running a batch script and somewhere the user has to access a database.

At this moment, a window made in vbscript would prompt asking the user to type in the login and password. (OK, Cancel buttons)

If the credentials are correct after the OK, the batch would continue according to planA, otherwise the batch would do something else going to planB. If (Cancel), it would return to the batch and the menu above.

```
@echo off
:Ini
echo   [1] Access database
echo   [2] Main menu
echo:
set /p Quest= What do you prefer (1 / 2)?       
if not '%Quest%'=='' set Quest=%Quest:~0,1% 
if '%Quest%'=='1' goto VBS
if '%Quest%'=='2' goto BATCH
echo Invalid option, please try again
cls
goto Ini

:BATCH
echo Heading for main menu ...
goto Main

:VBS
cscript login.vbs
(...)
```

-- How to continue and make the vbs?
-- How to capture the user information, validate it and go back to the batch for the planA  or planB ...
-- How to mask that password with ** ** ?

Help will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Better switch to vbscript entirely (or since you seem new to vbscript another language more recent and powerfull while keeping it easy like Ruby). Everything you start from the batch can also be done in Vbscript, you can use prompt for the menu and inputbox for the password and if it has to be masked use a the browser as UI like the script from Rob Vanderwoude here http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_password.php
Using this technique you can do all the UI/GUI in Internet Explorer and the logic in Vbscript.

If you decide to keep the batch approach, you can exit a vbs script with Wscript.Quit X, where x is the errorlevel you pass to windows when the script finishes, you can then trap that errorlevel in the batch. Alternative is to set or change an environment variable to do the trasfer of data, and last you can write data to textfiles easily in script and batch but the parsing of this in batch is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an intersting alternative as described below 
http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=103686.0

**VBSscript embeded in BATCH**

```
@echo off
:wscript.echo InputBox("Enter your password","VBScript-Batch")
findstr "^:" "%~sf0" | findstr /i /v ":Label" >temp.vbs
for /f "delims=" %%N in ('cscript //nologo temp.vbs') do set pass=%%N 
del temp.vbs

echo You entered %pass% 

:Label1

echo continue from here

If %pass%=="ok" echo Valid Password ! & goto EOF
If %pass%=="ok" echo Invalid Password !! & goto EOF

:EOF
pause
```

As you see, if we eliminate the "`& goto EOF`" the script works well. It sends the VBS input "pass" to the batch and the batch echoes "continue from here", from where the rest of your code goes.

However, it is not working as it should. Any help to make this **really** work ?

Comment: 29 views and no definite answer? Please folks, can anyone correct the codes ?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is ....

I have added in the existing VBSscript for "Internet Explorer version" the code :

**VBS SCRIPT - named Password.vbs (see full script in the above link from Peter)**

```
strPw = GetPassword( "Please, type your password:" )
WScript.Echo "Your password is: " & strPw

Sub Submit_OnClick 
dim filesys, filetxt, FormContent
Set FormContent =  document.getElementById("strPw")
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("C:\\temp.txt", 8, True)
filetxt.WriteLine(FormContent.value)
filetxt.Close
End Sub
```

**BATCH SCRIPT**

```
@echo off

cscript Password.vbs

findstr /B /E /M %strPw% temp.txt 
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo Password matched! & goto EOF
If not %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo Invalid Password !! & goto EOF

:eof
pause
```

The file temp.TXT should be sent to the c:\ with the information the user typed on the inputbox. The batch would read this input and compare to a set password and continue the coding...

How can I make this work?? the temp.TXT is not generated an so forth ...

BATCH and VBS gurus out there, any help to solve these problems is really welcomed !